# Data coming from Smart Contract showing TypeERror: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ethereum, web3js

I have a DApp with a Smart Contract which is holding some offers (id, price, owner etc.). I want to show that offers in my DApp fron tend.

First I am calling the Smart Contract and fetching all offers into an array with JavaScript:

```
// Load offers
      for (var i = 1; i <= offerCount; i++) {
        const offer = await contract.methods.offers(i).call()
        this.setState({
          offers: [...this.state.offers, offer]
        })
      }
```

Then I want to show the content of that array in a table:

```
<table className="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Price</th>
      <th scope="col">Owner</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {
      this.props.offers.map((offer, key) => {
        return (
          <tr key={key}>
            <th scope="row">{offer.id.toString()}</th>
            <td>{this.state.offers}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      })
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I don't know how to show the data properly on the table.

*Library: React*
*OS: XUbuntu*
*Browser: Chrome*

Comment: It only means that there is no `offers` on the `props` object. Shouldn't it be `this.state.offers` instead ?

Answer (score 0):

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This error is because this.props.offers is undefined.

You have to use this.state.offers, I think.

```
                {
                  this.state.offers.map((offer, key) => {
                    return (
                      <tr key={key}>
                        <th scope="row">{offer.id.toString()}</th>
                        <td>{this.state.offers}</td>
                      </tr>
                    )
                  })
                }
```